# Translation of the genitive gerund

Tags: verbs, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata, gerund, livius

I came across this sentence from Livy in Roma Aeterna, and although I believe I grasp the general meaning, I don't really understand the use of the genitive gerund 'sperandi':

> Deinde, cum minus agri esset quam quod dividi posset sine offensa etiam plebis (quoniam eos ad cupiditatem amplum modum sperandi incitaverat)...

My rough translation would be: 'then, since there was less land than could be divided without offense to the people (because he [Gracchus] had incited them [by/with hope?] to the desire of a large measure [of land]...'

I guess my question is twofold: am I right in translating it as 'by or with hope'? And if so why is it not a gerund ablative? I presume this is a common use case for the gerund genitive that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I've updated my translation to specify the agent.

Comment: thanks for adding that!

Comment: @William: Is it, "he incited them to desiring ('ad cupiditatem'...continuing with the accusative...) a greater measure ('amplum modum') of the hoping (genitive gerund, 'sperandi') [of the land] would be understood?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is quite common to see the word *[cupiditas](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=cupiditas)* or *cupido* and their derivatives together with the genitive gerund. Hence, most probably, *cupiditas amplum modum sperandi* should be understood as a single unit to mean "greed/desire/passion to expect/hope a large land".

There is some redundancy here, but I see no other way to parse this sentence. As *amplum modum* cannot really be attached directly to *cupiditas* as according to the examples we should see this in genitive or in with *ad* + acc.

Note that in the case of genitive or ablative gerunds, it is possible to attach a direct object instead of using the gerundive. (See [note 1 in A&G 503.a](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/gerund-and-gerundive))

Answer (score 1):

In d_e's answer, if "'cupiditas amplum modum sperandi' is to be understood as a single unit to mean, 'greed to expect a large land' why did Livy select the genitive-gerund, "sperandi", requiring the English translation, "of"?

Scouring the net for a translation I came across this from "Quizlet":

> "Then, when there was less of land than which was able to be divided, without offence even to the plebs, because Gracchus had incited them, toward a desire ('ad cupiditatem') of [the] expecting ('sperandi') a large measure [of land] ('amplum modum'),".

This does give a genitive role for the genitive-gerund, "sperandi", which was the OP's request.